# Quantum PSO and Charged PSO (PSO = Particle Swarm Optimizer)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, particle-swarm

I need to implement PSO's (namely charged and quantum PSO's). 
My questions are these:

- What Velocity Update strategy do each PSO's use (Synchronous or Asynchronous particle update)
- What social networking topology does each of the PSO's use (Von Neumann, Ring, Star, Wheel, Pyramid, Four Clusters)

For now, these are my issues. All your help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but [this paper](http://www.hvass-labs.org/people/magnus/publications/pedersen08simplifying.pdf) (quite recent) suggests that the PSO algorithm shouldn't be complicated too much, instead good behavior parameters can be found with a simple meta-optimization technique which is also described.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I think it does not matter.. PSO does not guarantee to converge anyway...

So you must not be that cautious for making such small decisions in this context..